# cannot open Files in administrator mode

Tags: pantheon-files

I have a problem, I cannot open Files as administrator by right-clicking the dock-icon and selecting 'New Window as administrator'.

Is that a bug or is it just affecting me? It works OK with Nautilus.

Comment: how are you trying to start Files? sudo pantheon-files ?

Comment: fixed March 1, 2017

Answer (score 3):

This is a known regression caused be a recent update.  A fix has been committed and should be released soon.  In the meanwhile using sudo pantheon-files in a terminal will work.

Comment: apparently a fix has been released today, so it works fine now